# Where are my dll's?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna

I am working in a game using XNA, now I want to use [Nclass](http://nclass.sourceforge.net/) to generate the class diagram with all the relationships and connectors. (I now Visual Studio 2010 comes with a built-in feature to generate class diagrams but it doesn't generate the connectors between classes).

NClass just need my dll, I have tried this with other projects and I find my dlls inside the debug folder, now with this project, the one made with XNA, I don't see any dll files, just .exe

Comment: Did you really add the dll the correct way or did you add it like a reference? If so, you only added a link/ path where the solution can find the dll.That may be the reason that you can't see the dll in the debug folder.

Comment: I don't have any issue in Visual Studio, my game works. I just can't find the "dll" file, that's what I am looking for.

Comment: Unless you have created a class library and added it as a reference to your game, there is no DLL file.  A DLL file is a class library.